# Cannot Read csv file

Tags: r, csv

I am new to R and I have this proplem: I have a set of csv files, each have 3 colums  with numeric values. I am traying to run a set of instructions to create categories that allow me to align the graphs of each of the files. This is so far my set of commands:

```
myFiles<-dir("C:\\Data\\")
myDeadVols<-as.matrix(read.csv("C:\\Data\\Dead Volumes.csv", header=T, sep="|", row.names=1))

myDeadVolsVec <- as.numeric(myDeadVols[,"t2_min"])*60 + as.numeric(myDeadVols[,"t2_s"])

names(myDeadVolsVec) <- myDeadVols[,"fileName"]

sampAnot <- names(myDeadVolsVec)

names(sampAnot) <- sampAnot

polyRead <- function(fileNames=NULL, mySep="|"){

dataList <- list()

for(tmpName in fileNames){dataList[[tmpName]] <-as.matrix(read.table(tmpName, header=TRUE, sep=mySep))}
return(dataList)}

polyReadMaritza <- function(fileNames=NULL, mySep="|", file2void=NA, fracTime=35, dataPerFrac=173){

dataList <- list()
for(tmpName in fileNames){
tmpMat<-as.matrix(read.table(tmpName, header=FALSE, sep=mySep))
tmpVoidTime<-file2void[tmpName]
tmpVoidPoints<-tmpVoidTime/fracTime*dataPerFrac
tmpAdder<-matrix(ncol=3, nrow=as.integer(tmpVoidPoints), data=0)
tmpMat<-rbind(tmpAdder, tmpMat)
tmpEvent<-rep(0, dim(tmpMat)[1])
fractMoves<-c(1:length(tmpEvent))[which(c(1:length(tmpEvent))%%dataPerFrac==0)]
tmpEvent[fractMoves]<-1
tmpMat[,3]<-tmpEvent
dataList[[tmpName]] <- tmpMat
colnames(dataList[[tmpName]])<-c("Distance.mm.", "Absorbance", "Event")}
return(dataList)}
```

So far everything seems ok but when I try to enter the fllowin command:

```
myDataList <- polyReadMaritza(myFiles, mySep="\t", file2void=myDeadVolsVec)
```

I have this error:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection.  In addition:
>   Warning message:In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'Beads.csv': No
>   such file or directory

Now, the path to 'Beads.csv' is C:\Data\Beads.csv, so I think that is because It does not read the complet path to 'Beads.csv' (which is the first of the files) but I thought that with "myFiles<-dir("C:\Data\")" I already specified the path. Any help is welcomed

Comment: Indent your code lines by 4 spaces to get it to format properly on SO.   All code should be minimal, self contained and complete including all library statements, if any, and all inputs. These 3 links contain more on how to ask questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You have actually get the list of files in the desired directory.

```
fileDir = 'C:/Data'
myFiles = list.files(path=fileDir, pattern='*.csv')
```

Then when you call `read.csv` you have to give R the full filepath with...

```
for(file in myFiles){
    read.csv(file.path(fileDir,file))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value that was returned by `dir` did not include paths. The default for "full.names" in `dir` is FALSE so unless your working directory is 'c://Data//' the `read.csv` call will not be looking in the correct location. Try:

```
myFiles <- dir("C:\\Data\\", pattern= "[.]csv", full.names-TRUE)
```

Comment: Thnak you very much, this got me further in the process, but now I have another error: 

Error in matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = as.integer(tmpVoidPoints), data = 0) : 
invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)

This is weird because I am stablishin my rows as:

nrow = as.integer(tmpVoidPoints)

Comment: The expected response to spotting an error and offering effective advice is to upvote or check the answer. If you then have a new problem that is unrelated to the first problem then it's time for a new question which would need to have a proper description of whatever file is being worked on.